# Object 'myvariable' not found.But my variable exists if i run str(dataframe)

Tags: r

I have the `Mroz` dataframe and i am trying to get the `median` of the `inc` variable of people that are assigned as "no" and later as "yes" in the `wc` variable. But it says that the `object wc does not exist` although when i run `str(Mroz)` it is written along with all the other variables.

```
str(Mroz)

mean(Mroz$inc[wc=="No"])

mean(Mroz$inc[wc=="Yes"])
```

Comment: Try `mean(Mroz$inc[Mroz$wc=="No"])` for `mean` or `median(Mroz$inc[Mroz$wc=="No"])`  to get median

Comment: I tried it but is says NaN

Comment: Use `na.rm` argument, `mean(Mroz$inc[Mroz$wc=="No"], na.rm = TRUE)` and same for `median`

Comment: It still says NaN

Comment: The wc variable take only yes or no so how can it be a number(cause from what i have seen nan stands for not a number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your requirement:** Need mean/median value of "inc" variable by the field in "wc" Column

For the above requirement, you can use below code

```
library(dplyr)
Mroz %>% group_by(wc) %>% summarise(mean(inc))
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked!Now i want to make a boxplot but when i write boxplot(Mroz$inc~wc,main="Income by age", it says object wc not found.It is the same problem again so what should i do now?(The variable wc is defined if i use the str command so i dont know what is it saying it is not found)